# ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Sub-message not read correctly (protobuf-net version 2.4.0)

Tags: c#, sockets, protobuf-net

I have two apps (SocketClient & SocketServer) both written in .NET core 2.1.
SocketClient (runs on unix machine) read a file which is of size ~10GB and sent the read bytes over Socket.

```
var serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(args[0]), Convert.ToInt32(args[1]));
using (var clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    clientSocket.Connect(serverAddress);
    using (var f = new FileStream(args[2], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var read = new BinaryReader(f, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            const int bufferSize = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int count;
            while ((count = read.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                int byteSend = clientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, count, SocketFlags.None);
                totalBytesSend += byteSend;
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent bytes {byteSend}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SocketServer (runs on windows machine) receives the sent bytes and try to de-serialized it:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    if (!stream.CanRead) return;
    while (true)
    {
        Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<SomeObject[]>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        Console.WriteLine($"{count += d.Length}");
    }
}
```

This code works fine with almost 96 million SomeObject successfully de-serialized (file contains ~101 million object) and after that it consistently breaks with message ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Sub-message not read correctly.

The file contains byte arrays obtained by calling following method repeatedly (with batches of SomeObject). The output of one single call is ~270KB which is being appended to file.

```
public static byte[] GetSerialisedWithLengthPrefix(SomeObject[] dto)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, dto, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated !! Thanks for reading.

The file creation logic is quite straight forward. SomeObject just contains three fields (string Id, string LogicalDateTime & double Value) and following method is being called by multiple threads

```
    Dump(SomeObject[])
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            requiredBytes = Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, SomeObject.ToArray(), PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        }
        lock (locker)
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(requiredBytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, that's going to be fun to debug. At a glance, it could be any of: a specific problem in one message, a glitch in the transport code (outside of the lib), a glitch in the serilaizer, a glitch in the deserializer. If it works for the first nearly-100-million, then I guess the code shown is more or less right... Unless it is a boundary condition thing and slowly creeping between frames? Is there anything you can give me.to help repro this? (I'm the author of protobuf-net). Is the data shareable at all? (Not necessarily via Stack Overflow)

Comment: Thx Marc for ur reply. Yeah I m already having fun while debugging this, I doubt my boss would be happy if I continue to have this fun :-). Regarding sharing the file I doubt I would be as file is in inside company's n/w. While reading your rely I realized I m debugging too many components at same time. So first I m going to cpy the created file from unix to windows (SCP) and then try to read the file locally and de-serialized it (avoiding Sockets). Also currently created file doesn't have prod like data so possibly I'll create another file with prod like data and will check the behavior.

Comment: I actually came back today to suggest exactly that: try copying the file completely, and deserialize the local file as a FileStream - that would rule out a lot of things (or point at them, if it fails)

Comment: I believe I found the root cause, after coping the file to windows I manually analyzed the file & found some garbage at the end of the file, which is the reason why things were breaking during de-serializing. I revisited my code for file creation & did't find anything fancy.  Eventually I noticed its a file size (10+ GB) causing issue, I was creating this file in my UNIX home directory which have a max quota of 10 GB & after that threads were not able to dump the bytes in file. I just moved the file creation path to some other location  on UNIX & after that things were fine even with socket.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that exception, in my case the structure of the class was changed and the deserialization would not work.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo {

   [DataMember(Order = 1]
   public int Bar;
}
```

if I change Bar to a `string` or `List<int>` that would create that issue.